# Looping over await Promise.all memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, promise

I run over 500 000 uids to fetch their associated data via a promise (promiseUserData(uid)). For some reason the memory usage is not cleared from loop to loop.

Roughly 4mb of data is used per loop and is not cleared from memory.

I am ignorant as how to fix this. Promise pooling also results in this issue.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

```
for (var i = 0; i <= numPasses; i++) {
    var subset = uids.splice(0, 1000);

    var userDataArray = [];

    var promises = [];
    subset.map((uid) => {
        promises.push(promiseUserData(uid).then((userData) => {
            if (userData) {
                userDataArray.push(userData);
            }
        }));
    });

    await Promise.all(promises).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error in Promises.all: ', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: *is not cleared from memory.* -> how do you measure that? Which timespan are you talking about? How much memory is left? ( cause some GCs only stop the world when neccessary)

Comment: I measured this with both memwatch-next and process.memoryUsage().heapUsed.

This code is running on nodejs and I have also manually called the GC but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What if you use `let` in the for loop instead of var? var is function scope and let is block scope, maybe using `let` will clear up the promises array, not sure why re assigning it would not clear up memory.

Comment: @HMR I have updated my code to only use let and const but no such luck. Will try a different method of looping.

Comment: @JamesBarnes Have you tried my approach posted in the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 1000 promises at once for every iteration.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying but I could imagine you are looking for something like `Bluebird.map()`. It is a handy way to process a lot promises with a set concurrency. Probably you are already using splice inside of that loop in order to process your promises in batches.

This approach requires you to install and import bluebird:

```
const userDataArray = [];
try {
  await Bluebird.map(uids, async (uid) => {
    const userData = await promiseUserData(uid);
    if (userData) { userDataArray.push(userData); }
  }, { concurrency: 100 })
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error in Promises.all: ', err);
}
```